# Chrome Dev Tools weird behavior randomly switching from elements to source for no reason

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-developers-console

I have noticed some weird behavior in Chrome Dev Tools in at least the current build I have and possibly a few others before...

This is my current Chrome Version: Version 78.0.3904.87 (Official Build) (64-bit)

So what happens is I open Dev Tools using F12, click elements, select an element to view using the element selector and then at some point for seemingly no reason, it switches to Sources.  This happens over and over again. Basically I am trying to do something with the element and then it suddenly switches to sources within 10 seconds and usually to some random weird js file.

No idea why this is happening, and it just started recently, within the past 2 weeks. It is literally driving me crazy because I like to play around with styles on elements in the HTML to see what they will do at times.

Any suggestions or is this some bug in Chrome now?

Comment: Click on *"Help > Report an issue"*

Comment: When it switches to the Sources view, is it stopped on a breakpoint? What have you done to debug the problem? Have you checked for event listener breakpoints?

Comment: No there are no breakpoints set at all. It just randomly switches